# Using reserved names as variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It seems there are some names that can't be used as variables is there some way to use them?
For example i've tried to used the name "class" as a variable:

```
    return Json(new { id = "1", title="evento", url="http://gsdfdsf.com", class="dsadas",start= "1487523292021", end= "1487523292021" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

As expected it gives error.
What is the turn around? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as anywhere else in C#, you can prefix identifiers with `@` to use  reserved keywords as identifiers:

```
return Json(new { 
    id = "1", 
    title="evento", 
    url="http://gsdfdsf.com", 
    @class="dsadas",
    start= "1487523292021", 
    end= "1487523292021" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: That seems to work, Thanks.